# XML with unclosed tags instead of attributes

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml that i want to read via php. The form of the file is like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<at>
    <f>ase
        <xx>20160801</xx>
        <S>AENE
            <G>100000,635</G>
        </S>
        <I>AAT
            <G>171434,245460</G>
            <A>103034,12080</A>
            <A>103534,15191</A>
        </I>
        <B>CCF
            <G>200000,10000</G>
        </B>
        <S>GGT
            <G>300000,10.4</G>
        </S>
        <S>HHT
            <G>300000,26.4</G>
        </S>
    </f>
</at>
```

The problem is that it does not use attributes. For example it uses: `<S>AENE`   instead of `<S name="AENE">`.
In that case I didn't find a way to take these data like:

```
$xml->at->f->S[0]
```

simplexml_load_string works ok, but how can i take for example this data? `<S>AENE`  (and put it in a variable). What I want is to be able to take info from the xml file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

```
$xml->f->S[0]
```

It was no necessary tags to close at each line as I thought. The mistake I had made was that I had used in the path and the `<at>` tags.